# I can't use RBAC on xenserver

Tags: rbac

I hope to use role based access control function for managing user on xenserver.

I have a server(xenserver 6.2) and a  AD Server(Windows 2008 R2).

AD Server is installed Windows 2008 R2, AD and DNS.

Then, I clicked Join Domain button on xencenter Users tab.

And, I input the Domain, User name, Password.

Domain is Fully Qualified Domain Name ( e.g. aaa.bbbbbb.com)
Username is 'Administrator' (default user).

But, I can't success.
Only show this error.

'XenServer was unable to contact your domain server to enable external authentication. Check that your settings are correct and a route to the server exists.'

How can i use RBAC function?

Answer (score 0):

The 3 most important things to check:

- the clock of XenServer and the AD Server are synchronised. Use the same NTP server for both of them.
- XenServer and the AD Server are both using the same DNS server.
- all the necessary ports (53, 88, 123, 137, 139, 389, 445, 464, 3268) are not blocked by a firewall

Also, see the XenServer Admin Guide, in the section about Configuring Active Directory Authentication:
http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/38321-102-714737/XenServer-6.5.0_Administrators%20Guide.pdf

Everything else failing, look at the dom0 logs in /var/log, especially xensource.log and messages.